# Material React Select Multiple: How i can remove from my array when i click in a selected element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm following this [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-hqlv9) example of how i can do a multiple material select.

This is my `array` that have all the possible options:

```
const permissionsGroupList = [
    { name: 'Sellers' },
    { name: 'Admins' }
];
```

This is my state that have my selected options:

```
const [groupPermissions, setGroupPermissions] = useState([]);
```

My function that add the selected option:

```
const handleChangeGroupPermissions = event => {
    setGroupPermissions(event.target.value);
};
```

My template component:

```
<InputLabel id="mult-check-permissions">Grupo de permissões</InputLabel>
  <Select
    labelId="mult-check-permissions"
    id="demo-mutiple-checkbox"
    multiple
    label="Grupo de permissões"
    onChange={handleChangeGroupPermissions}
    value={groupPermissions}
    input={<Input disableUnderline={true} />}
    renderValue={selected =>
      selected.map(value => <Chip key={value.id} label={value.name} />)
    }
  >
    {permissionsGroupList.map(permissionGroup => (
      <MenuItem
        key={permissionGroup.name}
        value={{ name: permissionGroup.name }}
      >
        <Checkbox
          checked={groupPermissions.some(
            group => group.name === permissionGroup.name
          )}
        />
        <ListItemText primary={permissionGroup.name} />
      </MenuItem>
    ))}
  </Select>
```

In the example, when i select a already selected option, the element is removed from the array `groupPermissions`. In my case, when i click in an already selected option, this element is putting again inside the array.

There's something more that i have to do to get a similar result of the sandbox example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that the sandbox Select gets data as an array of strings so you can simply map permissionsGroupList as an array of strings and not use the `name` property.

```js
const Select = MaterialUI.Select;
const Input = MaterialUI.Input;
const Chip = MaterialUI.Chip;
const MenuItem = MaterialUI.MenuItem;
const Checkbox = MaterialUI.Checkbox;
const ListItemText = MaterialUI.ListItemText;

const permissionsGroupList = [
  { name: 'Sellers' },
  { name: 'Admins' },
].map(p => p.name);//data in sandbox is NOT an array of objects

const App = () => {
  const [
    groupPermissions,
    setGroupPermissions,
  ] = React.useState([]);

  const handleChangeGroupPermissions = e => {
    setGroupPermissions(e.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <Select
      labelId="mult-check-permissions"
      id="demo-mutiple-checkbox"
      multiple
      label="Grupo de permissões"
      value={groupPermissions}
      input={<Input disableUnderline={true} />}
      onChange={handleChangeGroupPermissions}
      renderValue={selected =>
        selected.map(val => <Chip key={val} label={val} />)
      }
    >
      {permissionsGroupList.map(permissionGroup => (
        <MenuItem
          key={permissionGroup}
          value={permissionGroup}
        >
          <Checkbox
            checked={groupPermissions.includes(
              permissionGroup
            )}
            value={permissionGroup}
          />
          <ListItemText primary={permissionGroup} />
        </MenuItem>
      ))}
    </Select>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@4.9.7/umd/material-ui.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: i need this function in the select, when click in the label (or in the checkbox) check and put the value in the array

Comment: @veroneseWithS Updated the answer, in the sanbox the select `value={personName}` gets an array of strings, I changed permissionsGroupList to be an array of strings and changed the code that uses name property.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your solution is only adding a new item into your `groupPermissions` array.

What you should do:

- Check if the value is already present in `groupPermissions`
- If NOT, add it.
- If YES, remove it.

So your handle option should be something like:

```
const handleChangeGroupPermissions = event => {
    const { value } = event.target;

    if (groupsPermissions.includes(value) {
        // deep clone from your object array
        const newGroupsPermissions = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(groupPermissions ));
        newGroupsPermissions = newGroupsPermissions.filter(item => {
            return item.name !== value;
        });
        setGroupPermissions(newGroupsPermissions);
    } else {
        setGroupPermissions([...groupsPermissions, { name: value }]);
    }
};
```

Comment: Nope, it's much simpler than that. OP is passing wrong data type to value of Select